# PBEWithSHA256AndAES_256 decryption works on Windows not on Unix/Linux

Tags: java, linux, encryption, cryptography

I have the following code which works on Windows and Linux/Unix but will not decrypt an encrypted text that has been encrypted on Linux/Unix or vice versa.

I am aware that this will also generate the same encrypted text everytime, but I've removed some of the code to get to the very basic.

I am sure it's not related to Charset encoding, as the encoded String is the same on both OS, even the SecretKey is the same on both.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;

public class Encryptor {

    private static final String password = "passwordKey";

    private static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    private static final byte [] salt = "test salt as string".getBytes(UTF_8);

    public static String encrypt(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(password.getBytes(UTF_8));
        PBEParameterSpec parameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 10000, ivSpec);
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 10000);
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256AndAES_256");
        SecretKey key = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256AndAES_256");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, parameterSpec);

        byte [] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(UTF_8));
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(password.getBytes(UTF_8));
        PBEParameterSpec parameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 10000, ivSpec);
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 10000);
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256AndAES_256");
        SecretKey key = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256AndAES_256");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, parameterSpec);
        byte [] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64String(encryptedText);
        byte [] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decoded);
        return new String(decrypted, UTF_8);
    }

    public static void main(String args []) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String encryptedFromWindows = "eFRvTevgk/oslll+234r5tdsss==";
        System.out.println(decrypt(encryptedFromWindows));
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `ivSpec` from the `PBEParameterSpec`? It looks unnecessary to me.

Comment: Yes I thought initialisation vectors aren't required for PBE based encryption however if I remove it and just create a parameterspec with a salt and iteration count it encrypts fine but decrypt fails with a "java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Missing parameter type:IV expected"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a bug in the JDK version of _64.  Upgraded to _121 and it worked.  IT wasn't a known oracle bug but they had mentioned in another similar bug of issues with encryption in that release.